# Macro For MS Access for Batch Uploading

Tags: ms-access

I want to upload 1000 CSV file to a single table in MSAccess. Could someone help me with macro for that.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your CSV is fit to upload - no blank lines, no blank colums, column headers worded to suit Access (No spaces, no Reserved words, no barred characters). Then in the access ribbon click External data, select the file type you are importing, then browse to the file and create a new table. You will have to help access with the data types during the import process.